# Android finding views that aren't in the current view

Tags: android

beginner android programmer here,

In my main activity class, I have set the content view to `Home_Screen`. In this `Home_Screen` xml file - I have a ListView. And to describe the rows of this list view, I made another custom xml file called `row_layout` which looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textColor="@color/darkish_blue" >
    </CheckedTextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is, I need android to `findviewbyid` the CheckedTextView because it contains the check box that I need to use but it is giving me a nullpointer exception.

```
CheckedTextView chkBox = (CheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);
chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//<===== null pointer here!!
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                ((CheckedTextView) v).toggle();
            }
        });
```

I was thinking I might be able to incorporate the `row_layout` file into the list view in the `home_screen` where it can be found but I'm not sure how...
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: post your parent xml and oncreate method also. It will clear

Comment: Do you have an Adapter for your ListView?

Comment: @Clay You need to ignore all of the answers except for Philio's. You need to have an adapter and get the CheckedTextView for every row in the list as they are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first need to inflate the layout of your row layout before you can find the view. Try something like

```
View view = getLayoutInflator().inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
ChecedkTextView chkBox = (CheckeTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);
```

Your code wasn't working before there was no instance of the view with the id R.id.checkedTextView.

Comment: This is only a small part of the answer!

Comment: @bclymer Hi, that got rid of the error but now theres another one, on the line: `CheckedkTextView chkBox = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);` it's saying `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckedTextView`. I dont know whats going on, it's not an ImageView in my xml file.

Comment: That error is very verbose, the image you're looking up is actually an instance of `ImageView`, but you're explicitly trying to cast it to a `CheckedTextView`, check your XML to make sure your ids are correct.

Comment: @bclymer What would he do with `view` once he creates it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to drive the contents of your list with an adapter, this could be something that's built into Android or you can create your own. Generally if you're using custom views with anything other than cursors as a data source you're probably best off writing your own adapter (inheriting from BaseAdapter is a good start).

Within the adapter there is the getView() method which creates the view for each item in the list, using someone like @bclymer posted will allow you to implement your custom view and handle events etc.

I suggest you check the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to inflate the new view

```
   LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(yourcontext);
   RelativeLayout TheLayout = (RelativeLayout) myInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
```

then you can get the view

```
 CheckedTextView chkBox = (CheckedTextView) TheLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);
```

That'll do it.

Comment: Thats not working either, its saying cannot cast from linear layout to textview

Comment: Bah! My slack reading -  TheLayout = (RelativeLayout) myInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);

Comment: Now it says cannot cast from relative layout to textview... This is stupid.